# User Defined Function -- The name of the sheet where this formula exists

Tags: vba, excel

This is pretty easy, but I'm just oblivious to the necessary code. I want to make a User-Defined Function which returns the name of the sheet, where the function exists.

What I currently have:

```
    public Function SHEETNAME(X as integer) as String
        SHEETNAME = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(X).Name
    End Function
```

I'd like it to be useable on any sheet and return that sheet's name, rather than taking a numerical argument. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Function WhereAmI()
    WhereAmI = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

No UDF required. Try:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```